# Send bytes from .net server to flash

Tags: .net, vb.net, flash, tcp

I want to send data of bytes from .net server to flash client. i have created a simple .net tcp server but what code would i need to create the flash tcp client in order to receive bytes NOT string or xml, just bytes?

Thanks for any replies in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the flash binary socket.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697980/argument-count-mismatch-on-flash-netsocket-connect